# convert UTC to mysql dateTime javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm having trouble converting an example string: 'Sun Feb 02 19:12:44 +0000 2014'

to mysql dateTime format in javascript

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var d = new Date('Sun Feb 02 19:12:44 +0000 2014');
var month = d.getMonth();
if(month < 10)
month = "0" + month;
var day = d.getDate();
if(day < 10)
day = "0" + day;
hour  = d.getHours();
if(hour < 10)
hour = "0" + hour;
minute = d.getMinutes();
if(minute < 10)
minute = "0" + minute;
seconds = d.getSeconds();
if(seconds < 10)
seconds = "0" + seconds;    
var mysqlDate = d.getFullYear() + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + seconds;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert date time to mysql format using this code:

```
var myDate = new Date('Sun Feb 02 19:12:44 +0000 2014'),
    year = myDate.getFullYear(),
    month = ('0' + (myDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
    day = ('0' + myDate.getDate()).slice(-2),
    hour  = ('0' + myDate.getHours()).slice(-2),
    minute = ('0' + myDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2),
    seconds = ('0' + myDate.getSeconds()).slice(-2),
    mysqlDateTime = [year, month, day].join('-') + ' ' + [hour, minute, seconds].join(':');
```

However I would suggest to send it to backend as timestamp (`+(new Date('Sun Feb 02 19:12:44 +0000 2014'))`) or formatted string (`myDate.toISOString()`) and proceed with conversion there.